# Find rank of linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T_1$ ,$T_2$ , $T_3$ , mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then find rank of:

P. $T_{1}(x,y)=(x,x,0)$

Q. $T_{2}(x,y)=(x,x+y,y)$

R. $T_{3}(x,y)=(x,x+1,y)$

My textbook's answers are

- $P$ is linear transformation of rank 1,
- $Q$ is linear transformation
  of rank 2
- $R$ is not a linear transformation.

Please explain how this result came out? I am so confused.

Comment: Can you at least show $T_3$ is not linear? Do you know about matrices associated to linear maps?

Comment: yes I know. and I think it is a linear transformation of rank 2. May be my textbook is wrong

Comment: The book is right.

Answer (score 1):

For part a

Find Kernel which is by putting $x=0$. Use Rank Nullity theorem

For part b

Same as part a.Remember Kernel lives in $R^{2}$ (For this question !)

For part c

Use fact that linear transformation send  o vector to corresponding 0 vector

Comment: yes I sort it out sir. But I didn't get part c How it is it not linear? plz explain

Comment: what is T(0)...

Comment: i didn't get you.

Comment: let (x,y) in kernel then T_{1}(x,y)=(0,0) \Rightarrow (x, x, 0) = (0,0,0) \Rightarrow x=0, y=0 and z is arbit. therefore dim ker T = 1..is that ok

Comment: No, $(x,y)\in ker(T_1)$ only requires that $x=0$, so that the kernel is the $y$-axis. $T_1$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ so there are only two variables, $x$ and $y$, and "there is no $z$".

Comment: @T.Noor Kernel is that stuff which LT sends to identity. Since x=0 so kernel is (0,y). It means L.T sends all stuff of form (0,y) to (0,0,,0). So we have y as a free variable here.  It means we can take any value for y and it will be in kernel provided x=0.

Comment: @T.Noor Also for part c check that T(x+y)=T(x) = T(y), where x and y are of form (a,b)

Comment: Well for part c it is really enough to see that $T(0)\neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to come about the same solution.

For $T_i$, try and find a $2 \times 3$ matrix that represents the transformation $T_i$. If a matrix is not possible, then the transformation cannot be linear (because every linear transformation by definition can be written as $Mx=y$). If a matrix is possible, the number of non-zero rows in the row reduced matrix will be the rank of the matrix and therefore the rank of the transformation.

I'll only do Part (P) for you.

$T_1(x,y) = (x,x,0)$. Written in Matrix form, this is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Row reducing this transformation matrix, you get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

which only has one non-zero row. Therefore, $T_1$ is a linear transformation of rank 1.

I'll feel confident that you can do Part (Q) by yourself. For Part (R), note that there would be no way to get $x+1$ in the second dimension as merely a sum of $x$s and $y$s. Thus, no matrix can represent the transformation $T_3$, and it is not linear.